# Column in DataFrame isn't recognised. Keyword Error: 'Date'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm in the initial stages of doing some 'machine learning'.

I'm trying to create a new data frame and one of the columns doesn't appear to be recognised..?

I've loaded an Excel file with 2 columns (removed the index). All fine.

Code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('scores.xlsx',index=False)

df=df.rename(columns=dict(zip(df.columns,['Date','Amount'])))

df.index=df['Date']

df=df[['Amount']]

#creating dataframe
data = df.sort_index(ascending=True, axis=0)
new_data = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(df)),columns=['Date','Amount'])

for i in range(0,len(data)):
   new_data['Date'][i] = data['Date'][i]
   new_data['Amount'][i] = data['Amount'][i]
```

The error:

```
KeyError: 'Date'
```

Not really sure what's the problem here.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: (1) What line throws this error? (2) You can almost certainly solve this yourself by checking the columns of what you loaded in at each execution step.

Comment: Do `df.to_dict()`, right after `df = pd.read_excel('scores.xlsx',index=False)` and show us the results. It seems like, you do not have a `Date` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to @Grzegorz Skibinski's answer, the problem is after line 4, there is no longer a `'Date'` column. The Date column was assigned to the index and removed, and while the index has a name "Date", you can't use `'Date'` as a key to get the index - you have to use `data.index[i]` instead of `data['Date'][i]`.

Answer (score 3):

I think in line 4 you reduce your dataframe to just one column "Amount"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an error in the formatting of your `Date` column.

To check that you don't have an error on the name of the columns you can print the columns names:

```
import pandas as pd

# create data
data_dict = {}
data_dict['Fruit '] = ['Apple', 'Orange']
data_dict['Price'] = [1.5, 3.24]

# create dataframe from dict
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_dict)

# Print columns names
print(df.columns.values)

# Print "Fruit " column
print(df['Fruit '])
```

This code outputs:

```
['Fruit ' 'Price']
0     Apple
1    Orange
Name: Fruit , dtype: object
```

We clearly see that the "Fruit " column as a trailing space. This is an easy mistake to do, especially when using excel. 
If you try to call "Fruit" instead of "Fruit " you obtain the error you have:

```
KeyError: 'Fruit'
```